# Angular: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'cannotContainSpace')

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a custom ValidationFn in Angular. Somehow I always get the following error message:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'cannotContainSpace')
> at TutorRegistrationComponent_Template (template.html:31)
> at executeTemplate (core.js:9545)
> at refreshView (core.js:9414)
> at refreshComponent (core.js:10580)
> at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9211)
> at refreshView (core.js:9464)
> at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.js:9528)
> at tickRootContext (core.js:10754)
> at detectChangesInRootView (core.js:10779)
> at RootViewRef.detectChanges (core.js:22792)

This is how I made the Validator:

```js
export class UsernameValidators {

  static cannotContainSpace(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if ((control.value as string).indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
      console.log('username in validator (cannotContainSpace)', control.value);
      const valError: ValidationErrors = { cannotContainSpace: true };
      return { cannotContainSpace: true };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is how I used the Validator in my Page:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.registrationForm = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl(
      '',
      [Validators.required, UsernameValidators.cannotContainSpace],
      UsernameValidators.shouldBeUnique
    ),
    password: new FormControl(''),


  });
}
```

and in my view:

```
<ion-item lines="full">
   <ion-label position="floating">Username</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
   <div
     *ngIf="username.errors.cannotContainSpace && username.touched"
     class="alert alert-danger"
   >
     Username cannot contain space.
   </div>
   <div
     *ngIf="username.errors.required && username.touched"
     class="alert alert-danger"
   >
     Username is required.
   </div>
   <div
     *ngIf="username.errors.shouldBeUnique && username.touched"
     class="alert alert-danger"
   >
     Username is already taken.
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="username.pending">Verfügbarkeit wird überprüft...</div>
</ion-item>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AbstractControl.errors](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#errors) possibly returns null. Hence you need to use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for `username.errors` to prevent accessing chaining properties when it is `null` or `undefined`.

> The `?`. operator is like the `.` chaining operator, except that instead
> of causing an error if a reference is nullish (`null` or `undefined`), the
> expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined. When used
> with function calls, it returns undefined if the given function does
> not exist.

```
<div
  *ngIf="username.errors?.cannotContainSpace && username.touched"
  class="alert alert-danger"
>
  Username cannot contain space.
</div>
<div
  *ngIf="username.errors?.required && username.touched"
  class="alert alert-danger"
>
  Username is required.
</div>
<div
  *ngIf="username.errors?.shouldBeUnique && username.touched"
  class="alert alert-danger"
>
  Username is already taken.
</div>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xoxfqh?file=src/app/app.component.html)